# Handling of selection through javascript

Tags: javascript

Please refer to the link of my chart .

http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index    (Customized this )

Basically the requirement is that , only one month of selection can be made at a point of time .(From the child chart)

If the selection is made from left side , i am simply adding 30 to the other value

```
xmin = Math.floor(area.x1);
xmax = xmin+30;
```

But if the selection is made from the right side then how to handle this ??

(Means if the `xmax` is selected first then how can i handle the `xmin` value )??

Comment: do the opposite...set `xmax` to the selected value and `xmin` to that value minus 30 days

Comment: Thank you chad , you mean xmax = Math.ceil(area.x2);   and xmin = xmax-30 ??    But how can i handle this ?? any sample code please

Comment: @Chad: So depending where `area.x1` is clicked, this could potentially back or forward-date? Seems like a confusion solution to the end-user.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing too much about the situation, something like this should do:

```
// set the xmin to where they click
xmin = Math.floor(area.x1);

// make x-max the + 30 as you normally do
xmax = xmin + 30;

// now add a check to make sure we're not off the chart
// if we are, make the chart's last possible X value the
// x max, and subtract 30 from that to go backwards (and
// it may be a good idea to check if xmin is under the
// chart's min x value.
if (xmax > chart.xmax){
  xmax = chart.xmax;
  xmin = xmax - 30;
  if (xmin < chart.xmin){
    xmin = chart.xmin;
  }
}
```

Comment: Brad , this way i obtain the xmin and the xmax values xmin=Math.floor(area.x1);
xmax = Math.ceil(area.x2);       could you please tell how ur code works ??

Comment: @Kiran: So check against each other to find the greater number (for the top range) and lesser number (for the bottom range)? `xmin = area.x1; xmax = area.x2;  if (xmin > xmax){ xmin = xmin + xmax; xmax = xmin - xmax; xmin = xmin - xmax; } xmin = Math.floor(xmin); xmax = Math.ceil(xmax);` possibly?